# Como fazer site com multi linguas?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Desenvolvi um site em apenas uma língua mas agora queria metê-lo em diversas línguas para atingir público de outros países, é um site onde eu insiro bastante informação no meu backoffice que será mostrada para o meu público alvo

O que pretendo saber é qual seria a melhor maneira de por este site em diversas linguas?
Que conhecimentos adicionais precisarei de ter além dos que já tenho que são html,css,php e muito pouco de javascript!

Comment: o site é estático ou dinâmico?

Comment: dinâmico como referi insiro bastante informação no site através do backoffice

Comment: O que é backoffice? Seria um sinônimo de backend?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Seria um Administrador de Conteúdo.

Comment: @dvd fiquei curioso, tem algum link? Olhei no google mas ele não me entendeu muito bem

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Conheçe Wordpress? Seria tipo aquele administrador de conteúdo do Wordpress, onde vc posta, altera, exclui postagens etc.

Comment: Qual backoffice  você usa? Ou desenvolveu seu próprio?

Comment: Eu fiz um próprio! É só um site dinâmico onde posso postar conteúdo imagine noticias mas quero que o utilizador possa meter diferentes linguas!

Answer (score 1):

Um modo simples de fazer isso, seria com JS

exemplo:

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; 
        console.log("The language is: " + userLang);
        if (userLang == 'pt-BR') {
            var novaURL = "pt-br.html";
            $(window.document.location).attr('href',novaURL);
        }
        else {
            var novaURL = "english.html";
            $(window.document.location).attr('href',novaURL);
        }
```

navigator.language ou navigator.userLanguage, serve para verificar qual a linguagem utilizada no navegador, dessa maneira, estou utilizando 2 paginas estáticas, mas você pode utilizar da forma que quiser.

Comment: Pode explicar? É que não entendi

Comment: No exemplo tenho minha index.html, onde eu verifico qual idioma o navegador está usando, caso seja 'pt-BR', redireciono a pagina para minha pagina em portugues ( no exemplo se chama pt-br.html), se não, redireciono para a página em inglês. Isso é a forma estática de se fazer. Você pode ter 2 ou mais páginas e chama-las de acordo com o idioma do navegador do usuário

Comment: Você entendeu que eu tenho uma página e insiro lá conteúdo, e a tradução têm de ser feita automaticamente visto que não vou inserir em todas as linguas!

Comment: https://translate.google.com/manager/website/?hl=pt-BR